# Conflicting css styles in Chrome

Tags: css

Problem with Chrome when displaying my css styles:
The horizontal nav should have background grey and
text color black but on Chrome get maroon and text white.
On I.E 9 works fine but on Chrome not.
The style for the second nav looks ok.How do I resolve these conflicting styles.
Here is my codepen:
http://cdpn.io/uCgyF

Comment: The hex code you use (`#800000`) is maroon? It's showing up properly in Chrome because `aside` is a `HTML5` entity that Chrome understands, but `IE9` does not.

Comment: I want this css rule to be applied on first nav:  nav#navigation a:link,a:visited{
        color: black;
        background-color:grey;
        display: block;
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the shiv to your head

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

Add id to the ul and style accordingly as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/Kxgrq/)

```
<ul id="firstNav">

  nav #firstNav  a:link,a:visited{
    color: black;
    background-color:grey;
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: What I am trying tho achieve is to set background to grey and text color to  black on my first navigation. The second styles navigation must remain intact(and there are fine).There is no problem on I.E. I have a problem in Chrome because it displays background maroon and text white and I don't want that.

Comment: The problem is in the horizontal navigation that I want to apply the mentioned css rule.

Comment: `aside a:link` on line 101 sets the background to maroon and text-color to white

Comment: Is there a way to set the background of the horizontal nav to grey and color to black without using !important rule ? Because I know that aside sets  the background to marron and the text color to white.

Comment: Yes thank you for the solution! Can you tell what I was doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this solutions only inverts the problem.  In the fiddle, try clicking on a link in the #navigation and see what happens to the items in #firstNav

Comment: I would need to look at all your code, can you post a link to a live site maybe?

Comment: if you're going to take away the accepted answer, at least mark mine as usefull. and don't be so quick to accept in the future.

Comment: Now I have a problem with Firefox it's displaying second navigation right under the horizontal nav. I set margins but don't show on Firefox  only.Please Help ..

Comment: stop with the "Please Help" s$%t.  everyone who posts needs help. are you using a css reset?

Comment: I am using Firefox 29.0.1. On Chrome and I.E 9 margins shows out perfect but on Firefox fails.

Answer (score 0):

*(skip to the bottom for tl;dr)*

When I first loaded your pen, I saw things correctly.  But then I clicked on one of the header links and saw the behavior you describe.  That tells us that a `:visited` selector is probably the issue.  Take a look at your css code (I removed some to help illustrate the point):

```
nav#navigation a:link, a:visited {
    background-color:grey;
    color: black;
}
aside a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: maroon;
    color: white;
}
```

the comma (,) doesn't do what you think it does.  the comma in css is shorthand for writing the same definition twice, so if we didn't have that shorthand, your css would look like this:

```
nav#navigation a:link {
    background-color:grey;
    color: black;
}
a:visited { /* <-- oops! */
    background-color:grey;
    color: black;
}
aside a:link {
    background-color: maroon;
    color: white;
}  
a:visited { /* <-- oops! */
    background-color: maroon;
    color: white;
}
```

with your css, every visited link on the entire site (whether it is in your nav or not) will be white on maroon.

as a general rule of thumb, add a new-line after each comma in css.  It will help you see these errors more easily.

---

## tl;dr: do this:

```
nav#navigation a:link,
nav#navigation a:visited {
    background-color:grey;
    color: black;
}
aside a:link,
aside a:visited {
    background-color: maroon;
    color: white;
}
```